# assigning output to vdd in verilog

Tags: coding-style, verilog, system-verilog

Hi I'm trying to assign a led output to be on permanently and wanted to know how I would assign a constant value to an output, and if I can do it in my ucf file.

```
Net "0" = P16;
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What hardware are you targeting? I am assuming this is for an FPGA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do such a thing, but you could try using the inverse of your global reset signal to keep the LED on. The LED would be off when reset is asserted but that should be a very short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can tie signals high just by doing:

```
o_led_drive <= 1'b1;
```

o_led_drive is the signal that drives the LED.  That should work and illuminate your board as soon as the FPGa comes up.

Comment: To make sure I have things right o_led_drive is an output that I would have to map to my LEDin my ucf file right?